# Symfony Panther fails with alice bundle active

Tags: symfony, symfony-panther, alice-fixtures

I have a weird problem.
In my Symfony project I use a Postgresql database.

If I run my panther tests all things went well.

Now I have installed this bundle `hautelook/alice-bundle`.
As soon as I activate the `ReloadDatabaseTrait` in a panther test this test will fail.
It fails due to a timeout on a database connection.
For some reason the this bundle refuses new database connections.

I use the default settings from the alice bundle with a simple yaml file.

Anyone having a solution for this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Found it the test.env has a reference to the env=test.
This should be env=panther